# Pivot table using powershell

Tags: powershell

I have a CSV file called test with the consolidated statuses of machines with office365, windows and thirdparty. I have to create this CSV file into a pivot table with the percentages of the statuses individually like the picture below.

[Pivot table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uHfoO.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please show us what you have tried yourself. Note this is *not* a script factory. You will need to write the script yourself. If you run into a problem that isn't yet covered by the existing questions and answers, you might post your [mcve] here so that we might be able to help you further. See also: [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: The good to place to start with is: https://github.com/dfinke/ImportExcel